# ¿Como cambiar el estilo del mapa en Google Maps sin refrescar?

Tags: google-maps

Hola! Tengo esa duda. Actualmente tengo un sitio con el mapa de Google Maps y me encontré con esto: [Night mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/style-array?hl=es-419) y pues me gustaría poder implementarlo a mi sitio. Pero el problema está en que yo quisiera que el usuario que esta en mi sitio cambie, si lo desea, el estilo del mapa. Entonces, si el mapa esta con su estilo normal, y el usuario decide cambiarlo a modo nocturno, el mapa debería cambiar (sin refrescar el sitio) el mapa. ¿Como lograría hacer que cambie sin que refresque el sitio? Ya que lo tengo, pero para que cambie tengo que refrescar el sitio y no quisiera eso.

Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Jonathan, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento debes modificar tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado e investigado, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La misma documentación de **Google Maps Api** te brinda un ejemplo claro de la función que necesitas. Revisa la información [Aqui](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/style-selector?authuser=1&hl=es-419)

Comment: Maravilloso! Muchas gracias  :)

Comment: Si he respondido a tu pregunta por favor marcala como respuesta útil.